# Magnolia REST tools

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

When I try to display REST tools from the main page
[image]

It ends up with error

```
Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings
```

The page looks like below
[image]

Why does this appear instead of swagger docs? Is there any misconfiguration or maybe some privileges not set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that exception comes from Swagger side. Have you check If you have provided
'apiBasepath' at '/modules/rest-tools/config/apiBasepath'

Default value for preconfigured Magnolia bundles should be 'http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.rest' but you should adjust it to your configuration.

Cheers,

İlgün